# itext 7 Generating multiple pdf pages with 5 sections in a page : first page margin error

Tags: java, itext, pdf-generation, itext7

I have to generate pdf pages with 5 sections concept i.e

Section 1 : Document Header

Section 2 : Page header

Section 3 : Page Body

Section 4 : Page Footer

Section 5 : Document Footer

Section 1 and 5 only included on first page and the last page of the document.
Section 2 and 4 repeats on every page of the document.

Condition: Section 2 and 4 may be sometimes included/excluded on the pages.

Sometimes it may be 1 page document, and page may vary with the length of the document.

On generating pages on page events if multiple pages are generated and section 1 and 4 are not hidden I am able to calculate the body height and set margin on the document for each page and print the table in the body perfectly for multiple pages, but when i try with hiding section 1 and 4 the body content overlaps on the first page on the footer(only on the first page) for multiple pages.

Any possible solution regarding calculating the margin's for printing body on different case's would be helpful. I am trying to calculate the margin and set margin for each page inside page event handlers.

Comment: Why don't you simply add the required sections for the current page, then an area break, then the sections for the next page, another area break, etc.?

Comment: The problem is , the Page body content is dynamic i.e it may vary in length and we do not have a idea whether it will generate single page or multiple. But will try with area break and see if that works in my case. Thnx.

Comment: I think the conditions under which the sections shall appear and the locations where they should appear are not clear. Other than that create the document header at the very start, then add body content, and finally create the document footer at the very end. For page headers and footers use page events as explained on the itextpdf site. What I don't understand is *"Section 2 and 4 may be sometimes included/excluded on the pages"*... what does that depend upon?

Comment: When i set the section 2 and 4 as visible they should get rendered on the page, if they are set to hidden they shouldn't. when they are hidden, the margin changes right, in that case i am having trouble calculating the margins on the first page for the body on the bottom i.e footer, when there is multiple page generation possibility, By the way , i tried with the area break but to avail i couldn't get the expected output even with all possible scenarious.

Comment: Please refer the image, there the red mark is for the gap when the page footer section is hidden. [link]( https://ibb.co/knm3Ry)